# get div to be on different plane so that text can below it

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to create webpage that looks like the wireframe diagram above. The problem I am facing is with the div I have creatively designated as the "problem div".

The "problem div" needs to levitate on the div below it. It does not matter if it obsecures some of the content of "Central Content".

Since I am using

float: left;

on the div "Central Content", as I put info on the "problem div", it pushes the content of "Central div" further down.

Here is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="CentralContent">
                <div id="ProblemDiv"><b>Problem</b> <br><br><br><br>
                    Hello World
                </div>
</div>
```

And, here is the css:

```
body #CentralContent {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
}

#ProblemDiv{
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

I have tried using *clear: both* and *z-index*. But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the problematic div to interact with the rest of the content in any way, simply specify

```
position: absolute;
```

for it.
Also, are you sure your DOM nodes open and close where you meant to in your example? It looks odd.

Comment: and don't forget to add `position:relative` to `#CentralContent `

Comment: @YourFriend That's because you have the text _"Hello World"_ **inside** your problem div.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your HTML markup. It should be like this

```
<div id="CentralContent">
                <div id="ProblemDiv"> 
                 <b>Problem</b> <br><br><br><br>  
                </div>
Hello World

</div>
```

**Hello World** should be outside the ProblemDiv

Look at the solved result Here http://jsfiddle.net/4ejLcefs/1/

Whatever Nit said is also true but you will have to correct your markup.